# How to Use a Dynamic Filepath using Formidable in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, formidable

My uploaded form has a file and a field "filepath" which is dynamically generated and contains the desired filepath of the file I'm uploading.

Example:

```
filepath: "assets/images/asset-01-02/"
```

I'm trying to set this field as a variable so I can save the file to this directory to keep uploaded files organized.

Current code:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const formidable = require('formidable');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err)
            throw err
        }
        console.log(fields.filepath); //Output e.g. "assets/images/asset-01-02/"
    })
    form.on('fileBegin', (name, file) => {
        //Need to use fields.filepath after '/public/uploads/' 
        //e.g. __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + fields.filepath + file.name;
        file.path = __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + file.name;
    });
    form.on('file', (name, file) => {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });
});
app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 80...');
});
```

I need to get the `fields.filepath` value passed to the `form.on('fileBegin')` function but I'm not sure how to. I haven't come across any examples of this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am understanding your question, you are trying to send 'filepath' with 'multipart/form-data' or from client to server with uploaded files.
and you are trying to catch and set this 'filepath' using form.parse 'fields' into form.parse callback.

your code do not work simply because form.on('fileBegin') callback will execute before form.parse  callback.

here is execution order for callback in Formidable.(can change due to asynchronous functions)

1. form.on('fileBegin')
2. form.on('file')
3. form.parse()
4. form.on('end')

instead passing 'filepath' with 'form-data', send it with query like localhost/upload?filepath=assets/images/asset-01-02

and get it like

```
var filepath = req.query.filepath;
```

in your code